# Connect Exchange online powershell v3 with delegated access in multi tenant app

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I have an multi tenant application registered in Azure AD which got API Permissions assigned for Office 365 Exchange Online, more specifically 'Exchange.Manage' as delegated permission.

The idea is, that a user can sign in to the application with his Azure AD account and then the applications requests a token with scope 'Exchange.Manage' which can be used for exchange online powershell. I mostly followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps

However, instead of passing the certificate I wanted to use the -AccessToken parameter and use an access token with scope "Exchange.Manage'. The second parameter would have been the UserPrincipalName of the user currently using the application.

However, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException without further details.

The documentation often claims that multi tenancy with delegated access is possible, also when not using GDAP as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/partnercenter/exchange-online-gdap-app?view=partnercenterps-3.0.

The version of exchange online powershell I am using is 3.1.0

Any advice leading me to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to Exchange Online by **passing access token and User principal name**, try the below:

I created an **Azure AD Multi-Tenant Application** and added API permissions like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: The Access Token parameter is available for **`3.1.0-Preview1`** or later of the module.

To generate **access token**, I used the below script:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement

$TenantId = "organizations" 
$ClientId="ClientID"
   
$MsalParams = @{
   ClientId = $ClientId
   TenantId = $TenantId
   Scopes   = 'https://outlook.office365.com/.default'
}
$username = "xxx@tenant365.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "*****"
$Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $Pwd)
 
$MsalResponse = Get-MsalToken @MsalParams -UserCredential $Creds
$AccessToken  = $MsalResponse.AccessToken
  
$AccessToken
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, scope is **`Exchange.Manage`** like below:

[image]

Now, I am able to **connect to Exchange Online using the token** successfully like below:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName xxx@test.onmicrosoft.com -AccessToken $AccessToken

Get-ConnectionInformation
```

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, refer the below blog:

[Connecting to Exchange Online PowerShell by passing an access token](https://www.michev.info/blog/post/4249/connecting-to-exchange-online-powershell-by-passing-an-access-token) by Vasil Michev

Comment: Thanks, works great - turned out I named the wrong resource in the scope. Site note: I'm using .net MSAL library to get the token, so it also supports MFA and SSO.